# How can I convert empty objects as null with moshi and retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit2, moshi

I am using retrofit2 + Moshi in Kotlin to connect to a server.

All responses are wrapped with a *result* attribute. I have created a **generic data class** as below

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class CommonResponse<T>(val result: T?)
```

This is working flawlessly if result attribute is not empty for example:

```
{
    "result": {
        "bar": 1
    }
}
```

Having a data class Foo and using the generic with Foo

```
data class Foo(val bar: Int)

interface {

    @Path("/foo")
    fun getFoo(): CommonResponse<Foo>
}
```

But if the *result* attribute is empty as following

```
{
  "result": {}
}
```

I am getting JsonDataException due to bar cannot be null.

Is there any way for cases in which result attribute is empty consider it as null **using a generic adapter**?

What I have done so far is to catch JsonDataException exceptions and return null for those cases, but I am not happy with this solution due to result w/o data are valid responses. Also, I wouldn't be able to differ between a response without result or an invalid response.

Any idea?

NOTE: I cannot modify server responses.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way for cases in which result attribute is empty consider it as null?

Yes you need to make the property bar nullable as this is the exception with `Int?` and add a default value for the property so if it is absent then it can be set to null. So change `data class Foo(val bar: Int)` to `data class Foo(val bar: Int? = null)`

This will set bar to null for the following JSON:

```
{
    "result": {
        "bar": null
    }
}
```

...and

```
{
    "result": {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment but "bar" mustn't be null. That's key of my question

Comment: Was my other answer about creating a custom adapter any help? Thanks

Comment: The idea is to create a generic adapter, not for a specific response. That's why your response is not correct for me

Answer (score 0):

To set result to null if the JSON is empty you will need to create your own custom adapter for CommonResponse. So first of all you need to not generate an adapter for CommonResponse:

```
data class CommonResponse<T>(val result: T?)
data class Foo(val bar: Int)
```

...Then you need to create a custom adapter for a CommonResponse of Type Foo:

```
class CommonResponseAdapterFoo {

    @FromJson
    fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader): CommonResponse<Foo>{
        var fooObj: Foo? = null

        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            reader.beginObject()
            if (reader.nextName() == "result") {
                reader.beginObject()
                if (reader.hasNext()) {
                    if (reader.nextName() == "bar") {
                        val barValue = reader.nextInt()
                        fooObj = Foo(barValue)
                    }
                }
                reader.endObject()

            }
            reader.endObject()
        }

        return CommonResponse(fooObj)
    }
}
```

...and then you need to add this custom adapter to your moshi instance:

```
val moshi = Moshi.Builder().add(CommonResponseAdapterFoo()).build()
```

If you are wrapping multiple types in CommonResponse then you might have to create multiple custom adapters to accommodate all the different types